# How to know if PayPal is sending variables to notify_url

Tags: php, paypal

In my PHP web-app I'm using PayPal for transactions, as you know PayPal sends the transaction details to notify_url, now I want to know how I can be sure that PayPal is sending the data back to my web-app and not just another user faking the whole scenario... .

I can use session but isn't there anyway else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal has a IPN Notify Validate function: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/. It's all there for you.